# IntelliJ + SBT plugin + multiproject setup = Unresolved dependency?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I created a new project with the following structure (obfuscated names :):

```
Parent
|-- Child A
|-- Child B
```

The light build definition in `Parent/build.sbt` is as follows:

```
name := "Parent"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

version := "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

The full definition in `Parent/project/Build.scala` is as follows:

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyBuild extends Build {
    lazy val root = Project(id = "Parent",
                            base = file(".")) aggregate(projectA, projectB)

    lazy val projectA = Project(id = "Project A",
                           base = file("projectA"))

    lazy val projectB = Project(id = "Project B",
                           base = file("projectB"))
}
```

In `~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt`, I have this:

```
resolvers += "sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/"

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "0.11.0")
```

If I run `sbt gen-idea` in the folder `Parent`, all dependencies are downloaded properly and the project definitions are created correctly for `Parent`. However, sbt also tries to run the command in the subprojects, `projectA` and `projectB`. This fails with the following:

```
[warn]  module not found: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;0.11.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/me/.ivy2/local/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/scala_2.9.1/sbt_0.11.1/0.11.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Maven2 Local: tried
[warn]   file:/home/me/.m2/repository/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.9.1_0.11.1/0.11.0/sbt-idea-0.11.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.github.mpeltonen/sbt-idea/0.11.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.9.1_0.11.1/0.11.0/sbt-idea-0.11.0.pom
[warn] ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository: tried
[warn]   http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.9.1_0.11.1/0.11.0/sbt-idea-0.11.0.pom
[warn] ==== Scala-Tools Maven2 Snapshots Repository: tried
[warn]   http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.9.1_0.11.1/0.11.0/sbt-idea-0.11.0.pom
[info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.0.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;0.11.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.github.mpeltonen:sbt-idea:0.11.0 (sbtVersion=0.11.1, scalaVersion=2.9.1)
[warn] 
[error] {file:/opt/workspace/Parent/}ProjectA/*:update-sbt-classifiers: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.github.mpeltonen#sbt-idea;0.11.0: not found
[info] Created /opt/workspace/Parent/.idea_modules/project.iml
```

I get the same result if I move `~/.sbt/plugins/build.sbt` to `Parent/project/build.sbt`.

How can I prevent the children of `Parent` to execute `gen-idea`?

Comment: This is a pretty old question, but for anyone else that runs into this problem, my solution was using `resolvers in ThisBuild += "...." at "http...."` (further info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289766/what-is-the-difference-between-thisbuild-and-global-scopes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't go with disabling gen-idea for the sub-projects as the plug-in creates separate module for each sub-project.

I guessTechnically you can solve it by adding the resolver to each sub-project's build.sbt

```
resolvers += "sbt-idea-repo" at "http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/"
```

I am not sure however, why you need that as it should work without that. I had similar problem when the plug-in version was not the same as the sbt version (you can check you sbt version with about command)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was hoping there was a nicer way of solving this in SBT. :)

Comment: As I said I don't see this problem with my build.sbt and multi-projects. did you check the sbt version you use is the same as the plug-in?

Comment: Well, this is the output from `sbt about`: 
[info] This is sbt 0.11.1
[info] The current project is {file:/Users/...
[info] The current project is built against Scala 2.9.1
[info] sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.9.1

Comment: so try to use the matching plug-in. The repo has a version for 0.11.1 (http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.9.1_0.11.1/) but you set it to fetch the version for 0.11. change the addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "0.11.0") to addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "0.11.1")

Comment: Errrr, either I am blind, stupid or not looking well enough: I do see a version for SBT `0.11.1`, but it's version `0.11.0` of the plugin. This is what you are talking about, right? http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.9.1_0.11.1/0.11.0/. So with my current config, I am actually getting the correct plugin, if I am not mistaken...

Comment: Using `addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" %% "sbt-idea" % "0.11.0")` that is

Comment: they have a 0.11.1-Snapshot (http://mpeltonen.github.com/maven/com/github/mpeltonen/sbt-idea_2.9.1_0.11.1/0.11.1-SNAPSHOT/).But I am not sure if they do support 0.11.1 correctly (I am using SBT 0.11 and the 0.11 version of the plugin and it works well)

Comment: Not a big fan of SNAPSHOT dependencies. :) However, I did give it a try and it seems to be working now. Let's hope that there will be a release soon and that I won't run into problems later. Thanks for your help, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of the `aggregate` command says that it is intended to execute all commands also for the sub projects. So executing `compile` on `Parent` will also execute `compile` on `Project A` and `Project B`.

#### From the sbt docs

> Aggregation means that running a task on the aggregate project will
>   also run it on the aggregated projects. Start up sbt with two
>   subprojects as in the example, and try compile. You should see that
>   all three projects are compiled.

Reading further it says you can exclude certain tasks from the aggregation, so you want to do

```
aggregate in gen-idea := false
```

This answers your question, but I don't think it will make your setup work. I'm currently struggling with multi-project sbt, too.

Comment: Thanks, now I get the `aggregate in` part from the doc. :) Unfortunately, your suggestion does not work: SBT tells me `error: not found: value gen` in `aggregate in gen-idea := false`...

Comment: Try if the `aggregate in` works with a different task like `compile`. Maybe there are some problems because `gen-idea` is provided by a plugin. Then this might be a bug. Also I have managed to get my multi-project setup working with `gen-idea` without having to fiddle with aggregation.

Comment: How did you get it to work? Could you please post your configuration so that I can compare it with mine?

Comment: By the way, I do not get the error if I specify `aggregate in compile := false`... :/