# What is the difference between ThisBuild and Global scopes?

Tags: sbt

Can someone explain me the difference between writing these 2 lines:

```
resolvers in ThisBuild ++= appResolvers

resolvers in Global ++= appResolvers
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Read [Scopes](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scopes.html) for the full explanation.

I'll quote relevant parts:

> There are three scope axes:
>
> - The subproject axis
> - The dependency configuration axis
> - The task axis
>
> #### Scoping by project axis
>
> If you put multiple projects in a single build, each project needs its own settings. That is, keys can be scoped according to the project.
>
> The project axis can also be set to `ThisBuild`, which means the “entire build”, so a setting applies to the entire build rather than a single project. Build-level settings are often used as a fallback when a project doesn’t define a project-specific setting.
>
> #### Zero scope component
>
> Each scope axis can be filled in with an instance of the axis type (analogous to `Some(_)`), or the axis can be filled in with the special value `Zero`. So we can think of `Zero` as `None`.
>
> `Zero` is a universal fallback for all scope axes, but its direct use should be reserved to sbt and plugin authors in most cases.
>
> `Global` is a scope that sets `Zero` to all axes: `Zero / Zero / Zero`. In other words, `Global / someKey` is a shorthand for `Zero / Zero / Zero / someKey`.
>
> #### Referring to scopes in a build definition
>
> ```
> Global / concurrentRestrictions := Seq(
>   Tags.limitAll(1)
> )
> ```
>
> (`Global / concurrentRestrictions` implicitly converts to `Zero / Zero / Zero / concurrentRestrictions`, setting all axes to `Zero` scope component; the task and configuration are already `Zero` by default, so here the effect is to make the project `Zero`, that is, define `Zero / Zero / Zero / concurrentRestrictions` rather than `ProjectRef(uri("file:/tmp/hello/"), "root") / Zero / Zero / concurrentRestrictions`)

So as written above, `Global` sets all three axes to `Zero` whereas `ThisBuild` sets only the subproject axis to `ThisBuild`. This might make sense if you combine `ThisBuild` with other axis like configuration:

```
> set ThisBuild / Test / name := "test-name"
[info] Defining ThisBuild / Test / name
```

**Update February 2020**: As Stefan K noted in the comment [scope delegation rule](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Scope-Delegation.html) is a key fact that I didn't include in the above explanation.

> Rule 4: Given a scope, delegate scopes are searched by substituting the subproject axis in the following order: the given subproject, `ThisBuild`, and then `Zero`.

For example, if publishing configuration refers to `projFoo / version`, it would look in the order of:

1. `projFoo / version`
2. `ThisBuild / version`
3. `Global / version`

If the default setting is scoped to `Global`, like in the case of `version` setting (see `inspect version`), using either `ThisBuild / version` or `Global / version` would be able to set a version number for all projects in the build. The choice of `ThisBuild` here is almost by convention.

There are times where one might want to distinguish the two scoping. First is for source dependencies. sbt has a built-in support to depend on subprojects across multiple builds. In these cases, using `ThisBuild` would prevent one setting from spilling over to other builds.

There are also cases where some feature specifically refers to a globally scoped setting, often to configure the behavior of a command and/or the behavior of sbt itself. `Global / concurrentRestrictions` is an example of that. In this case, one must use `Global / concurrentRestrictions`.

Comment: Thanks, will have to read again that getting started guide because I didn't catch very well that axis part... btw thanks for your nice scalaz tutorials :)

Comment: I still can't tell the difference between `*/test:name` and `{.}/test:name`, help! See my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841527/difference-from-name-and-name-in-sbt

Comment: Does "filled in" mean "used as the fallback or default value"?

Comment: The key sentence from answer is: "So as written above, `Global` sets **all three axes** to `Global` whereas `ThisBuild` sets **only the project axis** to `{.}`. ".

Comment: This does not answer why the distinction of ThisBuild and Global is required and why one or another should be used. Are there any settings that exist in both and are normally different between them?

Comment: The missing link for me was this line in SBT's documentation: `Rule 4: Given a scope, delegate scopes are searched by substituting the subproject axis in the following order: the given subproject, ThisBuild, and then Zero. `

Answer (score 10):

This would probably be used in a plugin:

```
resolvers in Global ++= appResolvers
```

Whereas this could appear in your build definition:

```
resolvers in ThisBuild ++= appResolvers
```

thereby letting you override global default offered by plugin.

Within the same build definition, using either one will most likely have equivalent effect, because they are the bottom two in the delegates list.