# Difference from `{.}/*:name` and `*/*:name` in sbt?

Tags: scope, sbt, global

From some sbt document(e.g. [scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html)), I see:

```
{.}/*:name
```

means `name` in `entire build`(use `name in ThisBuild` to define it)

```
*/*:name
```

means `name` in `global project`(use `name in Global` to define it)

(PS: I ignored the config part `*:`)

But, I still don't know what is the difference between them, they seem exactly the same to me.

Is there any thing I can do with one rather than another one?

Comment: I've read this question, but still not clear: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289766/what-is-the-difference-between-thisbuild-and-global-scopes

Answer (score 2):

Whatever version you specified in ThisBuild will be applied to all projects in your build, overriding anything that was possibly defined in Global.

For example:  Key "version"

For Global scope it was defined in Defaults.scala with value "0.1-SNAPSHOT".

For your projects in this build you might want to overwrite that with:

```
version in ThisBuild := "3.0.1"
```

So, because [{.}/*:version] has precedence over [*/*:version], whenever you get "version" in your projects, you fetch "3.0.1" instead of "0.1-SNAPSHOT".

This pretty much explains the difference and how you could use one and not the other.

Comment: So `Global` has bigger scope than `ThisBuild`, because it can be a default value across different builds (e.g. defined in sbt, or in a sbt plugin), but `ThisBuild` is just reference current build, and can override the global default value?

Comment: Why would one want different values in Global and ThisBuild?

Comment: I also had a hard time in understanding this, but once it was mentioned that a plugin can define some setting in the Global scope it got clearer to me. Apart of plugins I don't see any use cases for using Global vs ThisBuild.