# How can I define my own setting or variable in build.sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I try to define my own setting that calculated by using value of name setting in build.sbt

```
// ...

val projectName_ = "project_name"
val projectName = projectName_.replace("_", "")

lazy val main_class = settingKey[String]("")
main_class := s"ru.company.${projectName}.${name.value}.Main"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
// ...
  Compile / mainClass  := Some(main_class.value),
  assembly / mainClass := Some(main_class.value)
// ...
)

lazy val rollout = taskKey[File](s"rollout_${projectName_}") := {
// Other using of main_class.value
}

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(stg, dm)
  .settings(
    name := "root"
  )

lazy val core = project
  .settings(
    name := "core",
    //...
  )

lazy val stg = project.dependsOn(core)
  .settings(
    name := "stg",
    commonSettings,
    rollout
  )

lazy val dm = project.dependsOn(core)
  .settings(
    name := "dm",
    commonSettings,
    rollout
  )
```

But i get error when i try to get value of my setting:

`Some(main_class.value)`

> Reference to undefined settings

How can I define variable with name setting that I will be able to use in settings?

Comment: I think you just need to move the `main_class := ...` line to the `commonSettings` list. This way, this setting will be defined in every project where you add `commonSetting`.

Answer (score 4):

When you do

```
lazy val main_class = settingKey[String]("")
main_class := s"ru.company.${projectName}.${name.value}.Main"
```

you're defining `settingKey` for any place which can access it, but setting its value only for the current project (which is `root`). For subprojects the value is undefined. So you have to set it for all projects.

Do something like this:

```
Global / main_class := s"ru.company.${projectName}.${name.value}.Main"
```

or

```
ThisBuild / main_class := s"ru.company.${projectName}.${name.value}.Main"
```

and `main_class.value` should not longer complain.

See the differences between `Global` and `ThisBuild` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18289766/what-is-the-difference-between-thisbuild-and-global-scopes#18305250).

Comment: Thanks! It looks great, but i got another problem.. `name.value` in subproject returns name of root project rather than name of subproject. But i need to get `name` of those subproject in settings of that i use main_class. I thought that lazy val should help me but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try defining `main_class` as `taskKey`